# Splitwise Create expense not reflected

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have been trying to create and expense entry in splitwise from my application using splitwise API (https://secure.splitwise.com/api/v3.0/create_expense).

Authentication : OAuth1.0

Request:

```
API: create_expense
request body:
{
 payment:false,
 cost: 100.00,
 description:”test”,
 users__0__user_id: current user id,
 users__0__paid_share:100.00,
 users__0__owed_share:50.00,
 users__1__user_id:friend user id,
 users__1__paid_share: 0.00,
 users__1__owed_share:50.00
}
```

Response:

Create query called successfully, got response 200. But the expense is not reflecting in Splitwise.

Answer (score 0):

There could be some validation errors at Splitwise API service side. In that case, the reponse is 200 OK but the response body contains the `error`.

Please refer to Splitwise API documentation errors. https://dev.splitwise.com/#errors